# Why is there an "Error in t(x.mean.A) %*% delta.A : non-conformable arguments" in oaxaca, after imputed missing?

Tags: r

Why is there an error

> "Error in t(x.mean.A) %*% delta.A : non-conformable arguments"

as I use `oaxaca` package, just after I filled the missing values with imputation?

I have searched and found that `%*%` is something about matrix multiplication.

But I don't get that how come `oaxaca` can work with no-imputation, then break down with imputation.

Before the imputation works, observations in `group A` and `group B` for `oaxaca` are `1209` and `981`; after the missing values are imputed, `group A` and `group B` for `oaxaca` becomes to `1209` and `1061`.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a reproducible example and a portion of the code that leads to the error.

Comment: The `t` in `t(x.mean.A)` means transpose. My guess is that the number of rows of `x.mean.A` increased via imputation but the rows of `delta.A` did not, hence the error. Therefore, you may want to apply your imputation or imputed values also to `delta.A`?

Comment: @Maxim.K forgive me, it's my first time to use stack overflow, I would figure how to present the code then, since I have another error which is different from but relevant with the problem in the beginning.

Comment: @aichao I have search what that `t` means too, after I asked the question. Many thanks to you and Maxim.K to reply my little question.

I have figured out what's wrong with the error. Since oaxaca can only take variables in numeric form, I put one of the variables in wrong form and I didn't notice. It can function correctly after I make that variable right.